# What security precautions should one take for a simple .io game with websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, websocket, socket.io

I am working on an .io game using node.js and socket.io. Being relatively new to the concept of websockets, I've spent these past few days looking into security measures such as JWT authentication and socket authentication, however, I don't think I fully grasp the purpose of it and whether it is necessary for my game.
In it, the player controls their unit with the WASD keys, so for the most part the client emits information only when the WASD keys are pressed or released. There is no registration and hence no database - users simply type out a name and start playing.
Is this a scenario where I should worry about authentication? Also, I'm considering potential DDOS attacks, such as for example sending an infinite loop that 'presses' and 'releases' the W key. In the server, pressing or releasing it only changes the value of a single variable. However, can firing at sockets rapidly cause the server to crash? If so, what is a surefire way to work around that?
Lastly, look at this example snippet and the questions in the comments:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.Server(app);
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var io = socketIO(server);
app.set('port', 1017);
app.use('/files', express.static(__dirname + '/files'));
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'iogame.html'));
});
server.listen(1017, function() {
    console.log('Server running on port 1017');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    sendID(socket); //could another user access the data that I send to this particular socket?
    socket.on('enterGame', function(data) {
//could this data be emitted by a different user in some way? (could a user 'pretend' to be on another user's socket and emit data?
    });
});
```

If the answer to either question is 'yes', then what is a good approach to avoid such malicious activity? Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: I would consider TLS (`wss`) a bare minimum. This would protect the server against "replay" attacks (when information is re-sent to the server with a spoofed IP address or by a man-in-the-middle)... This has nothing to do with registration, I just don't want some other player telling the server I pressed a key.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I still do not fully understand what steps I should undertake. How can I have socket.io use wss instead of ws?

Comment: I’m not a socket.io person, I was just pointing out one possible attack vector and one possible solution.